# Stirling's series for Log Gamma

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, gamma-function, bernoulli-numbers

I found this amazing formula, which expresses the logarithm of gamma function:
$$\ln\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{2}\ln{(2\pi)}+(z-\frac{1}{2})\ln{z}-z+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{B_{2n}}{2n(2n-1)z^{2n-1}}}$$
Link: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsSeries.html

Would anyone give me any hint or just an idea how does one derive this identity? I am pretty familiar with the Stirling approximation of the factorial (Gamma function) which is:
$$\Gamma(n+1)\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}\bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg)^n$$
I'll be tahnkful for any reasonable suggestions or links where i can find something about this.

Comment: You may prove that the coefficients appearing in [this proof of Stirling's approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1409131/44121) through creative telescoping are related to Bernoulli numbers via the [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: Otherwise, this is a standard application of the Euler-MacLaurin summation formula.

Comment: I put a very brief comparison at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615280/how-to-understand-intuitively-the-fact-that-logn-n-logn-n-o-logn/2615289#2615289